# Creating a factory that supports change over time

Tags: c#, architecture, factory

I have an *Engine* class, an *App* class that uses that Engine, and an interface *IEngine* that abstracts that:

```cs
public interface IEngine
{
    void Foo();
}

public class Engine1 : IEngine
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        //...
    }
}    

public class App1
{
    public void Do()
    {
        IEngine1 e = new Engine1();
        e.Foo();
    }
}
```

Since I can have multiple Engines, I'm implementing an engine factory that produces engines and returns them as IEngine:

```cs
public class EngineFactory
{
    public IEngine CreateEngine(string engineName)
    {
        //returns the right engine according to 'engineName'
    }
}
```

That way an App and an Engine are loosely coupled, and any *App* class will not reference concrete Engines.

Finally, I want to be able to add new methods to (all of) my engines. The natural thing would be to add those methods to *IEngine*, but if I'll do that, I'll have to recompile all the Apps that use *IEngine*. My solution is to create a new interface *IEngine2*:

```cs
public interface IEngine2 : IEngine
{
    void Goo();
}
```

But that will force me to change the *CreateEngine* method signature in my factory.

How can I avoid that? Should I change the factory to be generic? Should I use DI? Something else?

**Edit:** You can think about it this way- I'm responsible for the engines implementation, and my customers are implementing the Apps. Now there is a customer who needs a new capability from all of the engines, and I need to implement that capability without forcing all the other customers to recompile their apps (similar to an API implementation).

Comment: "The natural thing would be to add those methods to IEngine" - of course you would have to. How these apps would use the new method otherwise?

Comment: @Wiktor Existing apps can keep using IEngine. New methods are relevant to new Apps.

Comment: If this is so, you won't have to recompile your existing apps as `IEngine2` inherits from `IEngine`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla But now new apps cannot use the _IEngine2_ new methods because the factory returns _IEngine_. Unless I'll cast the returned type to _IEngine2_, which may result in a runtime exception.

Comment: You could create a new factory which returns `IEngine2` and don't touch `EngineFactory` at all?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes I thought about doing that (I could also add a _CreateEngine2_ method to my existing factory as well), but I'm looking for something more scalable. It seems as if those solutions are not the best practice.

Comment: It is not clear what is your situation. How you reuse the code, and why do you need to recompile, Does that `Goo` method really belongs to `IEngine` or it just extends `IEngine` in some way, etc. Without that it's hard to answer.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks anyway for trying. I'm simplifying the situation of course.. You can think about it this way- I'm responsible for the engines implementation, and my customers are implementing the Apps. Now there is a customer that needs a new capability from all of the engines, and I need to implement that capability without forcing all the other customers to recompile their apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem in the COM world, you should never modify a interface once it is published. The way COM usually works around this is using new version numbered interfaces that inherit from the previous version.

```
public interface IEngine
{
    void Foo();
}

public interface IEngine2 : IEngine
{
    void Goo();
}

public class EngineA : IEngine
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        //...
    }
}   

public class EngineB : IEngine2
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void Goo()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

For your factory you can have it always return a IEngine or have it be generic and the user must specify the minimum interface the item has to support.

```
public class EngineFactory
{
    public T CreateEngine<T>(string engineName) where T : IEngine
    {
        //returns the right engine according to 'engineName'
    }
}

public class App
{
    public void Do(EngineFactory factory)
    {
        //Creates a instance of EngineA
        IEngine e = factory.CreateEngine<IEngine>("EngineA");

        //returns a instance of EngineB
        IEngine eB = factory.CreateEngine<IEngine>("EngineB");

        //returns null
        IEngine2 e2 = factory.CreateEngine<IEngine2>("EngineA");

        //returns a instance of EngineB
        IEngine2 e2B = factory.CreateEngine<IEngine2>("EngineB");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks- this was my prefered soultion to begin with, but it means that I'm pushing the casting inside the factory. I was hoping to avoid casting at all through generics or DI, but after some thought I don't think that this is possible- some component will have to cast, be it the App itslef, the factory or the DI framework.

Answer (score 4):

A solution could be to use the capability pattern :

```
public interface IEngine
{
    bool TryGetCapability<T>(out T capability);
}

public interface ICapability1
{
    void Foo();
}

public class Engine1 : IEngine, ICapability1
{
    public bool TryGetCapability<T>(out T capability)
    {
        if (this is T)
        {
            capability = this as T;
            return true;
        }
        capability = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        //...
    }    
}    

public class App1
{
    public void Do()
    {
        IEngine e = new Engine1();
        ICapability1 cap1;
        if (e.TryGetCapability(out cap1))
        {
            cap1.Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

I used the engine class to implement the capability but on a real app it will normally be implemented on one class per capability.

Comment: Why the cast to `object` before the cast to `T` in the success case?

Comment: Compiler need to know statically that the cast is possible to allow a direct cast. We know at that point dynamically that it is possible but have no way to prove it to the compiler.

Comment: You could also implement TryGetCapability with `is` and `as`.  i.e.    `public bool TryGetCapability<T>(out T capability)
        where T : class
    {
        if (this is T)
        {
            capability = this as T;
            return true;
        }
        capability = default(T);
        return false;
    }`

Comment: Yes totally, I don't know why I used typeof instead in this case

Comment: Thanks, it's just don't scale with large and complex engines (similar notion could be achived with the Strategy pattern, with the same price)